# Using pytables to store a datetime so that pandas will automatically recognise

Tags: python, date, datetime, pandas, pytables

I'm creating a two step process that firstly processes lots of text into a HDF5 file using pytables.  Then secondly I process and analyse later using pandas opening with HDFStore.

As the content is mostly dynamic I create this table description using a dictionary.

```
tcols = { "Time"    : Time64Col(pos=0) }
# Then further columns are added dynamically
```

Each row has a datetime stamp which I want to future proof so do not want to use the pytables types TimeCol32 or TimeCol64 which works fine but has to go through a conversion when read by pandas converting with;

```
hdf=pd.HDFStore('store.h5')
df=hdf.get('/mygroup/mytable')
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'],unit='s',utc=True)
```

I know I can create the Pytable entry using a Int64Col and convert my times to nanoseconds since the epoch but how do I get pandas to automatically know this is a date without going through the conversion?

I noted when messing around with HDFStore table format to write that the table attributes have dtypes specified, would this be a way of telling pandas the correct interpretation?

```
index_kind := 'datetime64',
values_block_0_dtype := 'float64',
values_block_0_kind := ['A', 'B', 'C'],
values_block_1_dtype := 'datetime64',
values_block_1_kind := ['dateto']]
```

Comment: you are much better off to simply store using HDFStore in the first place; it will create the datetime columns correctly. Using the native datetime types is VERY hard in PyTables (and it is not entirely correct anyhow). Datetimes are stored in int64 native types. You cannot directly create the meta data.

Comment: Thanks Jeff.  I've tried the HDFStore (append) method and find it is massively slower even in my small test sample (pytables < 10secs, HDFStore=60secs).  I guess I'm going to have to stick with pytables and filter/convert dates before processing just to be efficient.  BTW I did group my data in batches before appending but this doesn't help much.

Comment: ok, not really sure what you are doing, ``HDFStore``, uses ``PyTables`` under the hood, so these shoulud be very similar in performance. I suspect you are have some dtypes that are off.

Comment: I might have to re-visit that as when profiling I find it spends 99% of the time in the HDFStore append.  Using Pytables I split each record (2MB) into multiple tables (80-120 bytes each row) and append to each group/table and it takes around 1 sec per record.  For HDFStore I group the data into an array before appending to the HDFStore tables. - there are around 60 tables for each 2MB record and only 10 records in my sample.

Comment: what you are doing should take just milliseconds maybe if you post a better example